# Como fazer uma busca por id em angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

Trouxe informações da api pelo `id`, porém coloquei direto no `ngOnInit` dentro do metodo o número do `id`. Queria saber como faço para buscar esses produtos no input ao apertar o botão?

Tenho a service que traz os produtos pelo id da API

```
listarProdutos(id: number):Promise<IResponse<any>>{
return this.http.get<IResponse<any>>(`mercado/produto/${id}`).toPromise();
}
```

E o component que está recebendo está da seguinte forma:

```
public produtos: ProdutosModel = [];

ngOnInit(): void{
this.listarProdutos(1);
}

contrutor(private produtoService: ProdutoService){}

listarProdutos(id){
this.produtoService.listarProdutos(id).then(response => {
this.produtos = response.data;
});}
```

E o HTML está assim:

```
<input type="text"> <button (click)="buscar">Buscar</button>

<table *ngFor="let produtos of produtos">
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>nome</td>
<td>data vencimento</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{produtos.id}}</td>
    <td>{{produtos.nome}}</td>
    <td>{{produtos.dataVencimento}}</td>
</tr>
```

Também tenho a model

```
export class ProdutosModel{
id: number;
nome: string;
dataVencimento: string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É bem simples isso, aliás tem várias formas de fazer, uma delas é passando um [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) no `input` e passar o valor que for digitado no parâmetro da função **buscar()**:

```
<input type="text" #ID> <button (click)="buscar(ID)">Buscar</button>
```

Na função **buscar()** vc executa o service conforme o valor recebido no parâmetro:

```
public produtos: ProdutosModel[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void{}

construtor(private produtoService: ProdutoService){}

listarProdutos(id){
  this.produtoService.listarProdutos(id).then(response => {
    this.produtos = response.data;
  });
}

buscar(id: any){
  let _id = id.value;

  this.listarProdutos(_id);
}
```

**OBS:** O mais correto no parâmetro do método listarProdutos() no service é ser do tipo **`string`** e não number, pq vai pegar esse parâmetro de um `input`, e todo valor de um input o tipo é string.

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples vou dá alguns exemplos:

Service:

```
listarProdutos(id: number){
return this.http.get<Mercado>(this.url + idB);
}
```

---

Component:

```
 constructor(private servico: HomeService) { }
  
  id: any;
  mercado: any;
  
  

    buscarId(){
        this.servico.listarProdutos(this.id).subscribe(objetos => this.mercado= objetos);
      }
```

---

```
Id: <input [(ngModel)]="id" type="text">
<button (click)="buscarId()">Botão</button>
<ul *ngIf="mercado!= null">
  <li>{{mercado.id}}</li>
  <li>{{mercado.nome}}</li>
</ul>
```

Vou deixar um link aqui para te ajudar:
https://digitalinnovation.one/artigos/busca-por-id-angular-8-basico

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).